# Strange cursor with last Kernel

Tags: fedora, kernel, kde, cursor

I have a fully updated Fedora 33 with 3 kernels installed: the last one 5.11.7-200.fc33.x86_64 and two 5.10 kernels. If I launch the 5.11, I see very strange cursors in KDE. The cursors in 5.10 kernels are the ones I always used.

Any clue?

**EDIT2:** Updated to kernel 5.11.8-200.fc33.x86_64: same problem.

**EDIT1:** By request, adding two cellphone pictures of the strange pointers, one in a console, the other in Firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with last kernel 5.11.9-200.fc33.x86_64.